# ERROR: git can't find remote helper for https on SUSE 12.4

Tags: git, https, git-clone, opensuse, make-install

On SUSE version 12.4 the git installation is made through binaries 2.12.2 (OFFLINE). `libcurl`, `expat` and `openssl` are  already installed

COMMANDS:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I $HOME/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/lib -L$HOME/lib64" ./configure --with-curl=$HOME --with-openssl=$HOME --prefix=$HOME --with-expat=$HOME
make 
make install 
git clone https://xxxx**
```

I have the following error:

```
git can't find remote helper for https
```

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: Tried anything from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22find+remote+helper+for+https%22 ?